# OS X bash For loop only processes one file in a directory

Tags: macos, bash, for-loop, ffmpeg

I'm trying to get this code to process all files in a directory : https://github.com/kieranjol/ifi-ffv1/blob/master/ifi-ffv1.sh

I run it in the terminal and add path to file `./ifi-ffv1.sh /path/to/file.mov`. How can I get it to move on to the next? I'll also need to make sure that it only processes AV files, such as *.avi/*.mkv/*.mov etc.

I've tried using while loops with shift but I can't get that to work either.

I've tried adding a specific path like here but I'm failing http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-loop-through-files-in-a-directory/

I've tried this https://askubuntu.com/a/315338 and it keeps looping the same file rather than moving on to the next one. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html this didn't help me either.

I know this is going to be a horribly simple solution but I'm very new to this.

Comment: There are lots of ways to "process" files; what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: So did you try `for f in /path/to/*.avi /path/to/*.mkv path/to/*.mov; do ./ifi-ffv1.sh $f; done`?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want to run that code I wrote on github on multiple files in a directory, one at a time. it transcodes, runs checksums, creates metadata xml etc.. @m7thon , do you mean that I make a second bash script with your code?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand your question. If you want to run the script `ifi-ffv1.sh` on multiple files in a directory, the command I wrote should do the trick (either in a bash file, or simply on the command line). So do you actually want to change the script itself so that is runs on all files of a certain type in a given directory?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm so unclear. yes I would like to alter the code so that it runs on all files of a certain type in a directory. However I'd like to keep the directory as a variable  so that I go to terminal, type ./ifi-ffv1.sh /path/to/file.mov and it runs the script on that file, and every other file in the directory.

Comment: But hopefully won't give any errors if there's only one file present!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually have any kind of loop in your code.  You need to do something like

```
for file in path/to/*.avi path/to/*.avg
do
  ./ifi-ffv1.sh "$file"
done
```

which will loop through all the specified files and substitute each one for `$1`

You can put whatever file names you want instead of the `path/to/*.avi path/to/*.avg`.  If you `cd` to the directory first, you can leave out the paths, and just use `*.avi *.avg`

To do it all in one script, do something like this:

```
cd <your directory>
for file in *.avi *.avg
do
    <your existing script here>
done
```

replacing all the `$1`'s in your script with `"$file"` (not duplicating any quotes you already have, of course)

Comment: Please consider putting double quotes around "$file" in case any files have spaces in their names.

Comment: So do I have to set the directory in the code, rather than leave it as a variable? As in, can I only add files to the script that are in one directory, something like /files_to_transcode? Right now, I can add a file from any directory and the script works. I'd like to use the script in a similar way, where I enter the path to a single file on a terminal but instead it picks up all other .mov or .mkv files in the directory.

Comment: Thank you! I used your code and changed path/to/ to the directory with my files. I did this by creating another bash file. I'd still like to edit my original code so that it does all files in a directory without having to use a second script, but I"m really happy with this solution. Your suggestion re `cd` to the path is something that would help as well.